# Auto add argument

Tags: bash, alias

I had a problem with electron6 and I found out that I had to launch it with the "--disable-gpu" argument, the problem is that I use many electron app.

I wanted to know if it was possible to automatically add this argument whenever /etc/electron/electron6 command is run, like an alias but for this path only ? Otherwise I would have to create lots of alias for all shell that I have and all the electron app.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias electron6='electron6 --disable-gpu'
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

First rename the existing binary

```
sudo mv /etc/electron/electron6 /etc/electron/electron6.real
```

Then create a replacement /etc/electron/electron6

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -a /etc/electron/electron6 /etc/electron/electron6.real --disable-gpu "$@"
```

and make sure it is executable. The `exec` will ensure that there are no extra processes. The `-a` will hide some of the deception.

Comment: Just to share knowledge: this method is called "[wrapper script](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript)".

Comment: And what if a package manager / installer pulls an update? I would not recommend moving binaries around for the sake of aliasing!